# Wifi continuously connects and disconnects and after computer crash

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, internet, network-manager

I'm a beginner on the Linux world.
Last day I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my desktop. 
This pc is connect to home network (where are other 2 computers with Windows 7) via usb Netgear Wifi Adapter N150 wna1100 to a router Netgear DGN1000.

The issue is that the pc continuously connect and disconnect from internet and after crash the pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thoughts would be to check if there are any other conflicting Wifi connections near by.

Try and get a "Wifi Channel Scanner" for the computer, verify what channel you are using on your wireless router/access point and see if there are any conflicting ones (e.g. Your channel could be 3 and there could be other wifi networks using the same channel or close to 3 either 2 or 4. Generally there should be a gap of 2 between each. For example, you are using 3 and another is using 5)

Make sure the drivers are up to date for the [Wifi adapter](http://support.netgear.com/).

Other than that you may have to get in contact with Netgear and ask them for a bit of support, as it could be a hardware issue.